# C++ system mkdir with path

Tags: c++, path, system, mkdir

Ran into a little snag here. I'm trying to make a directory inside of another directory using a variable directory name created by the function in use. Basically I want to store any created accounts in a directory named accounts that is separate from everything else. Here is what I have for my function:

```
system(("mkdir -p /home/user/Program/accounts"+accname).c_str());
```

The problem I am running into is that it creates the directory in Programs as accounts(accname) instead of in accounts with accname being the directory.

Example with accname = tim would currently look like accountstim inside of Program instead of tim inside of accounts.

Comment: why not use mkdir syscall?

Comment: If you can use [`experimental/filesystem`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) let me know and I'll write you the best answer. (I say the best cause if `filesystem` should become part of the standard officially circa C++17, then your code will be cross platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the -p flag, which will create all directories that you don't already have, so you're on the right track.

You'll need to add another slash to get a new directory. Without this extra slash, anything at the end of the string becomes part of the accounts directory, and not the name of a new directory:

```
system(("mkdir -p /home/user/Program/accounts/"+accname).c_str()); // note the slash after accounts!
```

That would solve your problem, but I advise against using the `system` function

**EDIT: Using mkdir only applies if you are running a POSIX system or other system that supplies a mkdir function. If you're on windows I don't know how that would be done.**

It's advisable to use the mkdir system call instead. If you're only creating one directory, the mkdir function call should be relatively straightforward. If you are running Linux you can read about it [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html).

Comment: I am using linux and both the direct answer and the link were very helpful. Although I must admit I face palmed a bit after seeing the extra / . I should have tried that and had no clue, but it makes perfect sense after the fact.